# "SelectFolderDialog" in .NET

Tags: c#, dialog, directory

There is no `SelectFolderDialog` in .NET but It is present itself in `Visual Studio 2010`.

I was wondering if there is any external .net component like this form.

Here is the VS2010 Dialog :

[image: SelectFolderDialog]

**Please Note that I dont want to use the [`FolderBrowserDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) and I need to get the Specific UI described in the `SelectFolderDialog`**

Comment: Indeed, the FolderBrowserDialog is horrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To gain access to the posh new [Vista folder selection dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776913.aspx) then I believe that you need to either:

1. Use a third party component, or
2. Use the native `IFileDialog` component.

Option 2 is easy enough using the [Windows API CodePack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack). You need to include the [`FOS_PICKFOLDERS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761832.aspx) option. The CodePack comes with lots of examples. I commend it to you.

Comment: I can use it but i want the specific ui described in the "SelectFolderDialog".

Comment: yes, the FolderBrowserDialog is one of those controls I hate seeing in apps, especially when I've come from copying the path to the folder I need, only to find there's no place to paste!

Comment: July 2023: CodePack link is dead.

Comment: @fadden rather than add a comment, you should edit the post to fix the broken link

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I did spend some time looking for a working link, but was unable to find one.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a library that provides access to the folder browser dialog etc. http://www.ookii.org/software/dialogs/

It is a wrapper around several Win32 dialogs, it provides both a Windows Forms and WPF variant, and it provides the "Vista style" SelectFolderDialog that you have displayed for example.