# Where can I get this select folder dialog?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm aware of the [FolderBrowseDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx) and [FolderBrowseDialogEx](https://github.com/haf/DotNetZip.Semverd/blob/master/src/Zip/Resources/FolderBrowserDialogEx.cs). However in my opinion these are both inferior to the below type of dialog:

[image]

This is more in line with the open file dialog, and gives access to the navigation pane (or whatever it is on the left).

I've seen it in a few programs (shown below is TortoiseHG), which makes me suspect that it a semi off-the-shelf component, and I'm just curious whether one is freely available. Unfortunately google-fu fails me and all I can find is the FolderBrowseDialog/Ex - so my question is, is there a pre-rolled version of this dialog box (if not in the .NET framework then elsewhere) that I can use?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["SelectFolderDialog" in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755119/selectfolderdialog-in-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is free and seems to provide customization options. Try this out.

https://github.com/scottwis/OpenFileOrFolderDialog

and http://www.lyquidity.com/devblog/?p=136

Comment: Thank you. Looks like exactly what I was looking for. But now I'd be interested in how you managed to find this - for the sake of improving my google-fu for next time.

Comment: just keywords - When I saw your question thing I remembered was "windows 7 style"